# Incorrect floating point math?

Tags: c++, floating-point

Here is a problem that has had me completely baffled for the past few hours...

I have an equation hard coded in my program:

```
double s2;

s2 = -(0*13)/84+6/42-0/84+24/12+(6*13)/42;
```

Every time i run the program, the computer spits out 3 as the answer, however doing the math by hand, i get 4. Even further, after inputting the equation into Matlab, I also get the answer 4. Whats going on here?

The only thing i can think of that is going wrong here would be round off error. However with a maximum of 5 rounding errors, coupled with using double precision math, my maximum error would be very very small so i doubt that is the problem.

Anyone able to offer any solutions?

Thanks in advance,

-Faken

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're not actually doing floating point math there, you're doing integer math, which will floor the results of divisions.

In C++, 5/4 = 1, *not* 1.25 - because 5 and 4 are both integers, so the result will be an integer, and thus the fractional part of the result is thrown away.

On the other hand, 5.0/4.0 will equal approx. 1.25 because at least one of 5.0 and 4.0 is a floating-point number so the result will also be floating point.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for your help. Should have come here earlier, oh well.

Comment: 1.25 is representable in base 2 as are 4.0 and 5.0. It should be exact.

Comment: Since it was an arbitrary example dmckee, I decided to go with the safer statement. :)

Answer (score 7):

You're confusing integer division with floating point division.  3 is the correct answer with integer division.  You'll get 4 if you convert those values to floating point numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Some of this is being evaluated using integer arithmetic. Try adding a decimal place to your numbers, e.g. `6.0` instead `6` to tell the compiler that you don't want integer arithmetic.

Comment: Actually, that would be a `.f`, not just `f`.

Answer (score 3):

```
s2 = -(0*13)/84+6/42-0/84+24/12+(6*13)/42;
```

yields 3

```
s2 = -(0.*13.)/84.+6./42.-0./84.+24./12.+(6.*13.)/42.;
```

does what you are expecting.