# Why can't I output a basic double in c++

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Incorrect floating point math?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236550/incorrect-floating-point-math)

Using C++ console app in visual studio.

```
 float percentCorrect;
 percentCorrect = ( 7 / 5 );
 printf("%f", percentCorrect);
```

output is 1.0000

OK so how do I get the correct decimal output??

Comment: Duplicate of [Incorrect floating point math?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236550/incorrect-floating-point-math) and about 4,000 others.

Answer (score 2):

7 and 5 are integers, so the compiler treats them as such and does integer division.

```
float percentCorrect; 
percentCorrect = (7.0/5.0); 
printf("%f", percentCorrect);
```

The above should print out the expected value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include a decimal: 7.0/5.0

Answer (score 1):

`7` and `5` are integer literals, so `7 / 5` performs integer division.

You need to have at least one floating literal for floating-point division to be performed:

```
float percentCorrect = 7.0 / 5.0;
```