# C compiler bug (floating point arithmetic)?

Tags: c, floating-point

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double fract=0;
    int tmp;

    //scanf("%lf",&fract);
    fract=0.312;
    printf("%lf",fract);
    printf("\n\n");
    while(fract>0){
        fract*=(double)10;
        printf("%d ",(int)fract);
        fract-=(int)fract;
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

this code shoud have an output of:
312

but somehing isn't going right.. i'm using devcpp 4.9.9.2 compiler...

Comment: One of the first rules of programming is that the problem is always in *your* code.

Comment: Also, "something isn't going right" really doesn't tell us anything. Why don't you tell us the output you get?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Incorrect floating point math?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236550/incorrect-floating-point-math)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Kernighan & Plauger say, in their old but classic book ["The Elements of Programming Style"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0070342075), that:

- A wise old programmer once said "floating point numbers are like little piles of sand; every time you move one, you lose a little sand and gain a little dirt".

They also say:

- 10 * 0.1 is hardly ever 1.0

Both sayings point out that floating point arithmetic is not precise.

Note that some modern CPUs (IBM PPC) have IEEE 754:2008 decimal floating point arithmetic built-in.  If using the correct types, then your calculation will be exact.

Comment: Well, in its way floating point arithmetic is precise, what is not so precise is converting floating point's typical base 2 mantissas to base 10 values.

Answer (score 6):

Floating-point arithmetic is confusing, and not guaranteed to behave intuitively.

Here's a good reference document: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). It's a long document, because it's a complicated problem.

In summary: Don't use floating-point values if you are relying on *exact* values.

Answer (score 6):

So you multiplied 0.3119999999999999999895916591441391574335284531116485595703125 by 1000 and truncated it and got 311? I don't see where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I forgot to mention the step of rounding off the last 6 bits after multiplying by 1000. ;-)