# Visual C++ rounding issue for currency data

Tags: c++, floating-point

In my financial related application, Double use as the data type for currency data. but recently I found Double having issue while rounding.

As example inside a double variable
                           35.25 stored as 35.249999999999999999999
                           35.75 stored as 35.750000000000000000001

so when does it trying to round the number to one decimal point
                           35.25 = 35.3
                           35.75 = 35.8

It means one number round to ceiling other to floor.

1. Could anybody suggest a solution for this issue?
2. What is the suitable data type should use for currency data in Visual C++

Comment: Simple: Don't use `double` for money. Use an integer for the lowest denominator. (such as cents for US dollars)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C compiler bug (floating point arithmetic)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002411/c-compiler-bug-floating-point-arithmetic)

Comment: Sure you want a Visual-C++ specific solution? Not one that you can reuse in companies where e.g. Linux+g++ is used? In other words, how about solutions that apply to every standards conforming compiler?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dealing with accuracy problems in floating-point numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590822/dealing-with-accuracy-problems-in-floating-point-numbers)

Answer (score 6):

The [IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) defines different data types as having different levels of significant digits.

For example the IEEE-754 [defines a double](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008#Basic_formats) as only having a 15.95 decimal digitis of precision.

So one option is make sure you stay within the maximum precision by rounding the **final value** to a number of significant digits that is less than this maximum limit.

But how you round is generally pre-defined by the type of finacial calculation you are doing.

For example FX spot prices are generally quoted to 4 deciml places and rates are quoted to 7 decimal places.

So without more information in what type of calculation you are doing it is a little hard to offer a solution.

Comment: hi Blake7, Thank you very much for the reply, could you give me a sample how does stay within the maximum precision.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is not rounding. It is [how floating point values are represented in the computer.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Internal_representation)

This is why `double` is not suited very well for currency related calculations.
As @Mysticial recommended, you might try using `int` and use Cents instead of Dollars or Euros as unit for your calculations.

This way addition, subtraction and multiplication should work as expected. You will have to take care of division operations though, as these will result in any decimal parts of the quotient being cut off, i.e. always rounded down.

The logic for converting the values into human readable units like Euros and Dollars can be entirely a matter of the user interface so only when displaying you have to take care of converting from Cents to Euros.

#### Sample

Here's a sample demonstrating the absence of precision loss.

```
int a = 25;             //  0.25 eurodollars
int b = 1000;           // 10.00 ED
int sum = a + b;        // 10.25 ED
int difference = b - a; //  9.75 ED
```

Comment: Hi foraidt, Could you give me some sample usage of `int` for currency related calculations.